# rest api does not list all users

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I followed the very first page in the [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) - created `UserSerializer` and `UserViewSet`. So, when I go to `127.0.0.1/myapp/` I see a nicely looking `Django Rest framework` api page. But the problem is, I see an empty list of users:

```
{}
```

To solve this problem and to see users in the database I created two new users manually:

```
user = User(username='Bob',password='Bob')
user.save()
user = User(username='John',password='John')
user.save()
```

And if I connect to sqlite and select from `auth_user` table, I see two rows corresponding to Bob and John, but if I refresh `127.0.0.1/myapp/`, I still see an empty list of users {}. I do not know how to solve this.

**EDIT**

I created a user another way:

```
User.objects.create_user(username='admin', password='admin')
```

and now I'm able to login, but still when I go to `127.0.0.1/myapp/` I see `{}`.

**EDIT**

I even visited admin page and created a new user. But {} still remains. It seems as if the very first "most simple" official example does not work. I can not list users and see them in my app.

Comment: can you post you urls.py and views.py ? 127.0.0.1/myapp/ urls is mapping to a view that returns user list ?

Comment: Can you also post the views and serializers that you are using? Most likely that's where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Example uses `users` endpoint

```
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

You are using `myapp` endpoint, and not telling us how you hooked it up in your urls.py.